# Sabre DesignatePrinterLLSRQ error: INVALID TICKET STOCK-0001

Tags: web-services, soap, sabre

I'm trying to do Issue Air Ticket workflow, but `DesignatePrinterLLSRQ` returns error:

```
INVALID TICKET STOCK-0001
```

Before this workflow, I'm doing Book Air Segment workflow. It works fine.

My request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <From>
                <PartyId>WebServiceClient</PartyId>
            </From>
            <To>
                <PartyId>WebServiceSupplier</PartyId>
            </To>
            <CPAId>4PFI</CPAId>
            <ConversationId>SWS-Test-4PFI</ConversationId>
            <Service>DesignatePrinter</Service>
            <Action>DesignatePrinterLLSRQ</Action>
            <MessageData>
                <MessageId>9314594d-6c40-406b-9029-b887b13906b6</MessageId>
                <Timestamp>2017-07-11T13:27:48Z</Timestamp>
            </MessageData>
        </MessageHeader>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <BinarySecurityToken>
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3255627259104687481!1005491!0
            </BinarySecurityToken>
        </Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <DesignatePrinterRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10"
                            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0.1">
            <Printers>
                <Ticket LNIATA="03388A"/>
            </Printers>
        </DesignatePrinterRQ>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My Response:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0"
                          soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">WebServiceSupplier</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">WebServiceClient</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>4PFI</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>SWS-Test-4PFI</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>DesignatePrinter</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>DesignatePrinterLLSRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>253992491200470611</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-07-11T13:38:40</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>9314594d-6c40-406b-9029-b887b13906b6</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">
                Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3255627259104687481!1005491!0
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <DesignatePrinterRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10"
                            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.0.1">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
                <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-07-11T08:38:40-05:00">
                    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <stl:Message>INVALID TICKET STOCK-0001</stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
        </DesignatePrinterRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

How can I fix this error? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
<Hardcopy LNIATA="03388A"/>
```

Comment: With that AirTicketRS return error TKT PRT NOT ASSIGNED/USE W*-0004

Comment: Fixed with `<Ticket CountryCode="AT"/>`

Comment: Let me know your request schema, even after adding countrycode=USA i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

@Yury,

This error occurs when the PCC you are trying to use is not allowed to issue or you have not correctly designated the ticket printer.

This is a suggested and functional flow from SABRE itself.

1. Change to a PCC with permission using the // *: ContextChangeRQ / *: ChangeAAA service
2. Enable ticket printer access permission with // *: ContextChangeRQ / *: ChangeDuty / @ Code = "4"
3. Designate the ticket printer with the DesignatePrinterRQ service

- CountryCode, You must validate the printer reference according to your region and airline.
- LNIATA, SABRE must specify the printer id to be used for the travel agency.